# how to add a subquery in select method on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

The code sample as following:

```
DB::table('orders')->select([
    DB::raw('SELECT COUNT(id) AS order_count WHERE type = 2'),
    DB::raw('SELECT SUM(id) AS order_sum WHERE type = 2')
])->paginate(20);
```

The selected fields are statistic fields,the subquery contain several conditions.I type the code like that,but the code can't work and make a syntax error,then i can't find out where the wrong is.who can help me? thanks!

Comment: you can check it by removing `[]` in select method

Comment: is this your full DB query? and `count` and `SUM` will be form `orders` table only?

Comment: please look at my answer,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should it be like this?

```
DB::table('orders')->select(
    DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS order_count'),
    DB::raw('SUM(id) AS order_sum')
)->where(type, 2)
->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

My original SQL like that:

```
SELECT
    o1.store_id,
    (SELECT Count(id) FROM `order` WHERE type = 2 AND `order`.store_id = o1.store_id) AS package_order_count,
    (SELECT SUM(price) FROM `order` WHERE type = 2 AND `order`.store_id = o1.store_id) AS package_order_sum,
    (SELECT Count(id) FROM `order` WHERE type = 3 AND `order`.store_id = o1.store_id) AS member_order_count,
    (SELECT SUM(price) FROM `order` WHERE type = 3 AND `order`.store_id = o1.store_id) AS member_order_sum
FROM
    `order` as o1
WHERE
    `o1`.store_id > 0 AND `o1`.`from` = 1
GROUP BY `o1`.store_id
```

and my php code like that:

```
DB::table('orders')->select([
    DB::raw('SELECT COUNT(id) AS order_count WHERE type = 2'),
    DB::raw('SELECT SUM(id) AS order_sum WHERE type = 2')
    DB::raw('SELECT COUNT(id) AS member_order_count WHERE type = 3'),
    DB::raw('SELECT SUM(id) AS member_order_sum WHERE type = 3')
])->paginate(20);
```

so,my code turn out an error.